# Tracking processed data using job bookmarks

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have been trying to process only the latest data from a s3 location enabling the job bookmark and trying to add the previously run data to the latest, and i am using mode("append") to write a parquet file, but data from the previous run has also run in the latest run so i am getting the duplicate records of the previously run when trying to load the final data.

I am not using dynamic_frame in my case, just simple glue job which reads the csv data from s3 location and writes a parquet file into output location. And enable the job bookmark, how can we traced the processed data using S3 timestamp based bookmark?